# Allow users to upload flash videos?

Tags: users, uploads, videos

I would like to allow users to upload videos to their profiles. I'm using the [couponpress theme](http://www.premiumpress.com/couponscript/) for wordpress, which is a coupon listing theme. It lets users upload images for their coupons or advertisements, but some of the users on my site have video (flv/swf) ads that they want to list instead of a still image.

I need to be able to upload a video for users. Does anyone know of a plugin or solution to achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: 14% acceptance rate will hold everybody back from answering your Qs...

Answer (score 1):

To do this you'll need a plugin that adds the flash format to the "let me in" list that WordPress has.

This may help:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-flash-embed/